# Searching with SQL Server database

Tags: c#, asp.net, web

I'm currently working on a website project and I'm almost done, except that I need to get my searching to work.

I would like it to work like this: On my masterpage there is a `asp:textbox` and a `asp:button`. When I type in a search word and click on my button I would like it to redirect to a search.aspx page - The problem is, that I don't know how to do that. I only got the method and it looks like this

```
public DataTable Search(string Keyword)
{
    return db.GetData(
                 "SELECT fldTitle, fldLang, fldCode from tblSnipets LIKE @1", 
                 "%" + Keyword + "%");
}
```

From there I don't know what to do.

Comment: You can have the button submit a post request to the search.aspx page, then call the search method there.

Answer (score 1):

Using classic ASP.NET and PostBack event without any patterns it will look like this:

1 - Add an event handler to the button click event.

```
<asp:Button id="Button1" Text="Search" OnClick="SearchBtn_Click" runat="server"/>
```

2 - Add SearchBtn_Click handler to the code behind file of your page and do a redirect to your Search page.
it will look like this:

```
void SearchBtn_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

3 - In this event handler write code that will redirect to your Search.aspx with parameters of your search criteria:

```
Response.Redirect("~/Search.aspx?criteria=" + Server.HtmlEncode(myTextBox.Text));
```

or close to this statement (check the MSDN)

4 - On the Search.aspx code behinf page in the Page_Load handler catch the parameters and call your method to get the data.

This is not the best solution, but it should work.

Comment: Make sure you sanitize all inputs being sent into SQL (parameterize them at least).